# Can't create a new Gradle project in Intellij Ultimate Edition 2017

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, ide

While starting a new Gradle based java project, i get

> Error:The modules ['helloworld', 'helloworld-app_test',
>   'helloworld_main'] point to same directory in the file system. Each
>   module has to have a unique path.

What's causing this ? How can it be solved?

Comment: Does it happen in 2017.2.3 version? If so, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA, it could be a regression of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155687.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter it in IDEA2017.2.3. AS this post : https://github.com/square/assertj-android/issues/174

I delete `.idea` directory then refresh Rebuild project. After rebuild project, IDEA will recreate `.idea` directory and `*iml` files.

It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This usually is the result of old iml files. Delete all .iml files and re import them using Android Studio. That worked for me.. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html